# tkinter strange phenomenon with buttons and images

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button

I don't know what to say because I am clueless on why this is not working.
The first button appears but the image does not the second and third button does not appear.

```
from tkinter import *

Master = Tk()
Master.geometry("1408x768")
Master.configure(background = "#000000")

# Top

Top = Frame(Master)
Top.configure(background = "#1C1C1C", width = 1024.0, height = 384.0)
Top.place(x = 0.0, y = -5.684341886080802e-14)

Nextimg = PhotoImage(file = "Next.png")
Next = Button(master = Top, background = "#0084FF", image = Nextimg)
Next.place(x = 624.0, y = 551.0, width = 100, height = 50)

# Bottom

Bottom = Frame(Master)
Bottom.configure(background = "#8C8C8C", width = 1024.0, height = 384.0)
Bottom.place(x = 0.0, y = 384.0)

Nextimg = PhotoImage(file = "Next.png")
Next = Button(master = Bottom, background = "#0084FF", image = Nextimg)
Next.place(x = 624.0, y = 551.0, width = 100, height = 50)

# Dashboard

Dashboard = Frame(Master)
Dashboard.configure(background = "#252525", width = 384.0, height = 768.0)
Dashboard.place(x = 1024.0, y = 0.0)

Continueimg = PhotoImage(file = "Continue.png")
Continue = Button(master = Dashboard, background = "#FF8900", image = Continueimg)
Continue.place(x = 1091.0, y = 359.0, width = 250, height = 50)
```

Comment: Note that all the buttons are *placed* outside the viewable area of their parent frames. For example `top` frame has size 1024x384, but `Next` button is placed at (624, 551), i.e. y > height.  Also you have used same variable `Nextimg` to store the first and second images, then the first image will be garbage collected.

Comment: What do you think `Top.place(x = 0.0, y = -5.684341886080802e-14)` is doing?

Comment: Its almost never the optimal solution to use `place()` for widgets like buttons. Most of the time you will want to use `pack()` or `grid()`.

Comment: I have set y = 0 and get the same result

Comment: @xdeltaxen Why are you using `place()` instead of `pack()` or `grid()`?

Comment: Because I use Figma and convert it to python for a nice design because I am extra

Comment: @acw1668 there are multiple frames and buttons belong to different frames in total it is 1080x1408 hence master.geometry

Comment: @xdeltaxen you issue is placement of the buttons is outside of viable window.

Comment: All the (x, y) values in `place()` are relative to the widget's parent, not the root window. Read carefully the example I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @acw1668 how do I make it relative to master? but still have it be in the other frame?

Comment: Why do you want to do it like what you said? It is not a good design.

Comment: Because it would be easier for me to do that than re-design everything I have already done.

Comment: I would suggest you to re-design what you have done because it is more maintainable later when your application grows bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue here appears that you are expecting your widget placement to be relative to the root window but in fact they are relative to the frames they are placed in.

Try this. Change all your buttons X/Y to 20 and see what I mean.
You will see all the buttons show up in the top left corner of each frame they are assigned to.

One issue is that you are using place to manage widgets and this is very bad for code maintenance. It is much better to use `grid()` and/or `pack()` to build your windows for several reasons.

Automatic weights to adjust placement based on window size and easy of maintainability as your code grows.

The issue you will see with your 1st and 2nd buttons is the 1st button does not show the image due to the reference being reassigned.
If you want to use the same image for both just save a reference once.
In this case you can remove the 2nd `Nextimg =`  from your code.

See what happens when we change the placement to 20's

```
from tkinter import *

Master = Tk()
Master.geometry("1408x768")
Master.configure(background = "#000000")

Top = Frame(Master)
Top.configure(background = "#1C1C1C", width = 1024.0, height = 384.0)
Top.place(x = 0.0, y = -5.684341886080802e-14)
Nextimg = PhotoImage(file = "Next.png")
Next = Button(master = Top, background = "#0084FF", image = Nextimg)
Next.place(x = 20, y = 20, width = 100, height = 50)

Bottom = Frame(Master)
Bottom.configure(background = "#8C8C8C", width = 1024.0, height = 384.0)
Bottom.place(x = 0.0, y = 384.0)
# Nextimg = PhotoImage(file = "Next.png") Removed this as it is why your image does not show up on the first button.
Next = Button(master = Bottom, background = "#0084FF", image = Nextimg)
Next.place(x = 20, y = 20, width = 100, height = 50)

Dashboard = Frame(Master)
Dashboard.configure(background = "#252525", width = 384.0, height = 768.0)
Dashboard.place(x = 1024.0, y = 0.0)
Continueimg = PhotoImage(file = "Continue.png")
Continue = Button(master = Dashboard, background = "#FF8900", image = Continueimg)
Continue.place(x = 20, y = 20, width = 250, height = 50)

Master.mainloop()
```

Note that I replaced your images with grey squares since I did not have your image to use.

Results:

[image]

A more conventional way to write this would be to use `grid()` or `pack()`.

Also I have rewritten the code to more closely fit PEP* standards.

See below example:

```
import tkinter as tk


master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry("1408x768")
master.configure(background="#000000")

top = tk.Frame(master)
top.grid_propagate(False)
top.configure(background="#1C1C1C", width=1024.0, height=384.0)
top.grid(row=0, column=0)
nextimg = tk.PhotoImage(file="gray.png")
tk.Button(master=top, background="#0084FF", image=nextimg).grid(row=0, column=0)

bottom = tk.Frame(master)
bottom.grid_propagate(False)
bottom.configure(background="#8C8C8C", width=1024.0, height=384.0)
bottom.grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(master=bottom, background="#0084FF", image=nextimg).grid(row=0, column=0)

dashboard = tk.Frame(master)
dashboard.grid_propagate(False)
dashboard.configure(background = "#252525", width = 384.0, height = 768.0)
dashboard.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2)
continueimg = tk.PhotoImage(file="gray.png")
tk.Button(master=dashboard, background="#FF8900", image=continueimg).grid(row=0, column=0)

master.mainloop()
```

Results:

You can also manage spacing of the widgets from the edges if you like. That can be done by providing a padx/pady parameter to the grid().

[image]